# How to check if browser places overflow at 'html' or 'body'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-plugins, webkit

I found out that webkit browsers place the overflow at the 'body' level while the rest do it at the 'html' level. How do I differentiate using javascript or jquery?
I want to use animate({scrollTop: ...}, ...) but don't want to use "body, html or stop(true, true). What can I do other than that?
It would be great if there could be any way to differentiate according to the browser.

Comment: Can you point to a testcase that shows the behavior difference you're talking about?  That would help with figuring out how to best detect it...

Comment: Its like this..I have to use $("body").animate for webkit and $("html").animate for others....so that I can animate the scrollTop property, how do I do that?

Comment: I see.  Looks like WebKit doesn't implement http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrolltop correctly.  What happens if you simply animate this on both `<html>` and `<body>`?  If you don't have explicit overflow styling on body, this should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really want to differentiate the browsers from the client-side you could use the javascript to find the browser and apply the changes through that based on different browser.

this is a code that i obtained from internet that exactly differentiate the browsers.

```
var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
         // Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
      // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;              // Chrome 1+
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode; // At least IE6


if(isFirefox){
    //do the change
} else if (isChrome){
    //do the change
}
```

Comment: Since the spec actually describes the behavior, presumably one of the browsers has a bug.  But if you write the code the way you propose it will break when the bug is fixed....